# How can I test a pull request before merging it?

Tags: git, github

I work as a part of a team. Our process is to create a separate branch, work on the separate branch, then push that branch to 'origin' and make a pull request to master.

I am trying to get better with the default command line Git.

Then another person makes a pull request on a branch. Is there an easy way to pull that branch to my local and check out the branch so I can test the code before approving the pull request?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's even the possibility of checking out the "remote branch" directly, no need to create a local branch (git will say you are working on **detached HEAD** state), so, using Sajib's example:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/whatever
```

Comment: I do this a lot because it avoids creating a local branch. Checkout, test, forget about it.

Comment: Instead of `git checkout origin/whatever`, you can also use `git cherry-pick origin/whatever` (if you want to preserve the current branch and HEAD pointer).

Comment: @SajibKhan I don't think it creates a new local branch. it would create it if you did `git checkout -b whatever` instead.

Comment: With a little more practice, now I can say; it would create a local branch if you provided the name of the _remote_ branch, no need for `-b`: `git checkout whatever`. Tnen you would end up with a local branch called `whatever` started from `origin/whatever`.

Answer (score 8):

You can checkout the branch (say, `feature`) where pull request is created.

```
$ git fetch

# create a new branch 'test-feature' with 'origin/feature' history
$ git checkout -b test-feature origin/feature
# now test here
```

You can merge `master` into `test-feature` branch and test if all is ok!

```
$ git pull origin master
# test more
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to fetch branch:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you can list all files that have been changed:

```
git diff --name-only origin/master
```

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I am the creator of Pull Dog, but I truly believe it solves this particular issue very well.

I made a [GitHub app called Pull Dog](https://dogger.io). For every pull request you open, it takes your `docker-compose.yml` file, creates a new test environment, runs `docker-compose up` on it, opens the exposed ports in the firewall, and posts a link with connection details for each of these ports.

[Portainer](https://github.com/portainer/portainer) (15k stars on GitHub as of writing) is using it for their project. You can go look at any of their pull requests to see how it behaves.

Highlights:

- Fully managed. No need to host anything.
- Took me 47 seconds to set up for my own project.
- Free plan available for the most basic needs, and cheap otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As some have suggested you can check out the branch in question. You could also pull the pull request itself, as described by Github [here](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).

I made [a tool](http://trytopico.com/) which automatically deploys all pull requests to unique temporary testing URLs on your own server, which can be handy if you would like your QA team to be able to test pull requests without the need of having a development environment on each of their machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using github go to the pull request and scroll to the down.click on command line instructions(beside Merge pull request button). expand it. follow step one. the changes will be pulled to your local in another branch.
[image: see this image for clarification]